# can github composite action inputs use self inputs as default values?

Tags: github-actions

does this work?

```
name: "test"
description: "test"
inputs:
  a:
    description: "Description of a"
    required: false
    default: ${{ inputs.b }}
  b:
    description: "Description of b"

runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - name: docker-login-build-push
      run: |
        echo {{ inputs.a }}
        echo {{ inputs.b }}

      shell: bash
```

I want if the value of a is not set the value of b be set as the value of a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`inputs.<input_id>.default`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#inputsinput_iddefault) doesn't say anything about the use of `inputs` in `default`.

But, you can test and verify it yourself.

I ran this simple test resulting in this **error**:

> Unrecognized named-value: 'inputs'. Located at position 1 within expression: `inputs.a`

That means it's **not supported**.

---

Here's the action and workflow that I used to verify this:

`.github/actions/test/action.yml`

```yaml
name: Test
description: Test

inputs:
  a:
    description: a
  b:
    description: b
    default: '${{ inputs.a }}'

runs:
  using: composite

  steps:
    - name: Test
      shell: bash
      run: |
        echo 'a: ${{ inputs.a }}'
        echo 'b: ${{ inputs.b }}'
```

`.github/workflows/ci-test-action.yml`

```yaml
name: test_action

on: workflow_dispatch

jobs:
  ci:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Test
      uses: ./.github/actions/test
```

Here's the **complete error logs**:

```
Error: /home/runner/work/test/test/./.github/actions/test/action.yml (Line: 11, Col: 14):
Error: /home/runner/work/test/test/./.github/actions/test/action.yml (Line: 11, Col: 14): Unrecognized named-value: 'inputs'. Located at position 1 within expression: inputs.a
Error: GitHub.DistributedTask.ObjectTemplating.TemplateValidationException: The template is not valid. /home/runner/work/test/test/./.github/actions/test/action.yml (Line: 11, Col: 14): Unrecognized named-value: 'inputs'. Located at position 1 within expression: inputs.a
   at GitHub.DistributedTask.ObjectTemplating.TemplateValidationErrors.Check()
   at GitHub.Runner.Worker.ActionManifestManager.ConvertRuns(IExecutionContext executionContext, TemplateContext templateContext, TemplateToken inputsToken, String fileRelativePath, MappingToken outputs)
   at GitHub.Runner.Worker.ActionManifestManager.Load(IExecutionContext executionContext, String manifestFile)
Error: Fail to load /home/runner/work/test/test/./.github/actions/test/action.yml
```

---

Regarding:

> I want if the value of `a` is not set the value of `b` be set as the value of `a`.

this should work:

```yaml
${{ inputs.a && inputs.a || inputs.b }}
```

i.e.

```bash
echo '${{ inputs.a && inputs.a || inputs.b }}'
```

You may set `inputs` as env vars, apply these validations, and use those inside shell/Bash like this:

`.github/actions/test/action.yml`

```yaml
name: Test
description: Test

inputs:
  a:
    description: a
  b:
    description: b

runs:
  using: composite

  steps:
    - name: Test
      env:
        A: '${{ inputs.a && inputs.a || inputs.b }}'
        B: '${{ inputs.b }}'
      shell: bash
      run: |
        echo "A: $A"
        echo "B: $B"
```

Comment: in `.github/actions/test/action.yml` why have you set a `required: false` ?

Comment: @AminBa: Because I wanted to be explicit that it's not required. Not related to your question directly. You can ignore that.

Comment: and why do move `A: '${{ inputs.a }}'` to env? why not use it directly?

Comment: @AminBa: I find it convenient to list all those inputs and outputs and then use them in scripts. I try to keep my `action.yml` minimal. It's a design choice. Examples: https://github.com/iamazeem/substitute-action/blob/main/action.yml and https://github.com/iamazeem/security-headers-action/blob/main/action.yml

Comment: and where `${{ inputs.a && inputs.a || inputs.b }}` should be used? It is a little unclear to me. your answer specified what does not work but does no clearly specifies what works

Comment: @AminBa: That depends on your implementation. The example in your question only has `echo`. It should work with `echo`. Answer updated accordingly.

Comment: is this the same as what you suggested? https://stackoverflow.com/a/76243138/11065874

Comment: @AminBa: Please check the last section of my answer. I updated it with the example.

Comment: if you dont have `required=false` can you have `default: 'some default value'`?
it is irrelevant to the question. I would remove the default value. b is not an optional input

Comment: another comment is that I have a small preference to keep business logic outside of GitHub Action's functionalities. That is why I propose [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76243138/11065874). do you think it will work and is the same thing?

Comment: @AminBa: Yes, you can choose to handle everything in `run` section. That should work.

Comment: do you know what is the problem here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76244713/does-github-actions-have-prolblem-with-special-charcters-in-env-variable

Comment: @AminBa: Regrading your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76242713/can-github-composite-action-inputs-use-self-inputs-as-default-values/76242893#comment134452279_76242893), **if you dont have `required=false` can you have `default: 'some default value'`? it is irrelevant to the question. I would remove the default value. b is not an optional input**, yes, you can have the default value without `required: false`. And, removing `required: false` doesn't make an input **required**. Only specifying `required: true` explicitly makes it required.

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution I am going with

```
name: "composite-test"
description: "test"
inputs:
  a:
    description: "If a is not applicable, set its value to an empty string if - the value of b will be used for it"
  b:
    description: "Some description for b"

runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - name: echo
      run: |
        A=${{ inputs.a }}
        B=${{ inputs.b }}

        if [ "$A" = "" ]; then
          echo "$B"
        else
          echo "$A"
        fi

        echo "$B"


      shell: bash
```