# Does github actions have problem with special charcters in env variable?

Tags: github-actions

```
name: my workflow

on:
  push:
env:
  BASE_IMAGE_ARTIFACTORY_HOST: "some-host"
  BASE_IMAGE_ARTIFACTORY_LOGIN_USER: ${{ secrets.CLOUD_SERVICE_ACCOUNT }}
  BASE_IMAGE_ARTIFACTORY_LOGIN_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.CLOUD_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD }}

jobs:

  build:
    name: build
    runs-on: [ .... ]
    container:
      image: ....
    steps:
      - name: install-docker
        uses: ....
      - name: checkout
        run: |
          echo ${{ secrets.CLOUD_SERVICE_ACCOUNT }} | sed 's/./& /g'
          echo ${{ secrets.CLOUD_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD }} | sed 's/./& /g'/g'
          docker login -u ${{ secrets.CLOUD_SERVICE_ACCOUNT }} -p ${{ secrets.CLOUD_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD }} some-host
```

successfully logs in and returns

and returns

```
s v c _ r e g _ c l o u d _ a c c t 
9  r a n d o m u n r e a l / [ n m B g c | &
```

---

but

```
name: my workflow

on:
  push:
env:
  BASE_IMAGE_ARTIFACTORY_HOST: "some-host"
  BASE_IMAGE_ARTIFACTORY_LOGIN_USER: ${{ secrets.CLOUD_SERVICE_ACCOUNT }}
  BASE_IMAGE_ARTIFACTORY_LOGIN_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.CLOUD_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD }}

jobs:

  build:
    name: build
    runs-on: [ .... ]
    container:
      image: ....
    steps:
      - name: install-docker
        uses: ....
      - name: checkout
        run: |
          echo $BASE_IMAGE_ARTIFACTORY_LOGIN_USER | sed 's/./& /g'
          echo $BASE_IMAGE_ARTIFACTORY_LOGIN_PASSWORD | sed 's/./& /g'
          docker login -u $BASE_IMAGE_ARTIFACTORY_LOGIN_USER -p $BASE_IMAGE_ARTIFACTORY_LOGIN_PASSWORD $BASE_IMAGE_ARTIFACTORY_HOST
```

fails to log in to docker

and returns

```
s v c _ r e g _ c l o u d _ a c c t 
" 9 r a n d o m u n r e a l / [ n m B g c | & "
```

**can characters such as / [ | &  be the reason for the problem?**

**How should I fix it without changing the password preferably?**

---

**Alternatives I tried**

```
name: my workflow

on:
  push:
env:
  BASE_IMAGE_ARTIFACTORY_HOST: "some-host"
  BASE_IMAGE_ARTIFACTORY_LOGIN_USER: "${{ secrets.CLOUD_SERVICE_ACCOUNT }}"
  BASE_IMAGE_ARTIFACTORY_LOGIN_PASSWORD: "${{ secrets.CLOUD_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD }}"

jobs:

  build:
    name: build
    runs-on: [ .... ]
    container:
      image: ....
    steps:
      - name: install-docker
        uses: ....
      - name: checkout
        run: |
          docker login -u "$BASE_IMAGE_ARTIFACTORY_LOGIN_USER" -p "$BASE_IMAGE_ARTIFACTORY_LOGIN_PASSWORD" "$BASE_IMAGE_ARTIFACTORY_HOST"
```

and

```
name: my workflow

on:
  push:
env:
  BASE_IMAGE_ARTIFACTORY_HOST: "some-host"
  BASE_IMAGE_ARTIFACTORY_LOGIN_USER: "${{ secrets.CLOUD_SERVICE_ACCOUNT }}"
  BASE_IMAGE_ARTIFACTORY_LOGIN_PASSWORD: "${{ secrets.CLOUD_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD }}"

jobs:

  build:
    name: build
    runs-on: [ .... ]
    container:
      image: ....
    steps:
      - name: install-docker
        uses: ....
      - name: checkout
        run: |
          docker login -u $BASE_IMAGE_ARTIFACTORY_LOGIN_USE -p $BASE_IMAGE_ARTIFACTORY_LOGIN_PASSWORD $BASE_IMAGE_ARTIFACTORY_HOST
```

and

```
name: my workflow

on:
  push:
env:
  BASE_IMAGE_ARTIFACTORY_HOST: "some-host"
  BASE_IMAGE_ARTIFACTORY_LOGIN_USER: ${{ secrets.CLOUD_SERVICE_ACCOUNT }}
  BASE_IMAGE_ARTIFACTORY_LOGIN_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.CLOUD_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD }}

jobs:

  build:
    name: build
    runs-on: [ .... ]
    container:
      image: ....
    steps:
      - name: install-docker
        uses: ....
      - name: checkout
        run: |
          docker login -u "$BASE_IMAGE_ARTIFACTORY_LOGIN_USER" -p "$BASE_IMAGE_ARTIFACTORY_LOGIN_PASSWORD" "$BASE_IMAGE_ARTIFACTORY_HOST"
```

and

```
name: my workflow

on:
  push:
env:
  BASE_IMAGE_ARTIFACTORY_HOST: "some-host"
  BASE_IMAGE_ARTIFACTORY_LOGIN_USER: ${{ secrets.CLOUD_SERVICE_ACCOUNT }}
  BASE_IMAGE_ARTIFACTORY_LOGIN_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.CLOUD_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD }}

jobs:

  build:
    name: build
    runs-on: [ .... ]
    container:
      image: ....
    steps:
      - name: install-docker
        uses: ....
      - name: checkout
        run: |
          docker login -u '${{ env.BASE_IMAGE_ARTIFACTORY_LOGIN_USER }}' -p '${{ env.BASE_IMAGE_ARTIFACTORY_LOGIN_PASSWORD }}' '${{ env.BASE_IMAGE_ARTIFACTORY_HOST }}'
```

in all cases, I get

```
Error response from daemon: Get "https://some-host/v2/": unknown: Bad credentials
```

---

I also tried the command locally

```
U=svc_reg_cloud_acct 
P=9randomunreal/[nmBgc|&
docker login -u $U -p $P some-host
```

logs in successfully

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253654/discussion-on-question-by-amin-ba-does-github-actions-have-problem-with-special); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.